# Twitter API on BlueMix

Tags: twitter, ibm-cloud

I'm getting familiar with data on Twitter-Insight on Blue-Mix.  I have noticed that there is a added field "USER-GENDER". As this field is not in user profiles, I tried to look in the documentation but it's not mentioned how the gender is evaluated (by Surname? by previous tweets (this would probably means that a specific algorithm is used? which one?). 
If you can point me to any documentation that I missed that would be highly appreciated. 
Martin

Comment: Which documentation did you look at?

Comment: The one on Blue Mix and PowerTrack.

Comment: Can you please link that in your answer? It's important to give all details to links and references plus effort you did on Stackoverflow so people can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably referring to the [Insights for Twitter documentation](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/Twitter/index.html#twitter) that lists gender information as an enrichment.
That information can be directly obtained from the Twitter profiles, by analyzing the profile data. There are other services including Twitter itself that provide gender information based on the profile data. How the gender is derived is not documented. :)

Comment: Thanks! Knowing that there is no answer is probably an answer :-)